# Realizar un left join entre un select y una tabla

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

tengo el siguiente, select que me funciona bien y me genera la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT a.productid, a.name, a.productmodelid, c.productdescriptionid,c.cultureid, ROUND(AVG(b.rating),2)
FROM product a
LEFT JOIN productreview b ON a.productid = b.productid
LEFT JOIN productmodelproductdescriptionculture c ON a.productmodelid = c.productmodelid
WHERE c.cultureid = 'en'
GROUP BY (a.productid, a.name, a.productmodelid, c.productdescriptionid, c.cultureid)
ORDER BY AVG(b.rating) LIMIT 3;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora necesito agragarle otra columna que viene de otra tabla, es decir necesito hacer un left join entre la tabla que resulta de este query y una tabla diferente a las que he usado, la llave con esta otra tabla es el campo productdescriptionid, esta es la otra tabla que necesito traer el campo description, si alguien me puede decir que modificar en este query para hacerlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu consulta SQL es inconsistente. El predicado en la claúsula `WHERE` convierte el `LEFT JOIN` en `INNER JOIN` tras bambalnas. ¿Estás seguro que es eso lo que quieres?

Answer (score 0):

Aparte del hecho que tu consulta SQL es inconsistente, la forma más simple de hacer lo que quieres es utilizar tu consulta existente como "expresión tabular" y luego el join resulta trivial.

Por ejemplo:

```
select 
  x.*,
  tabla_2.*
from (
  -- consulta SQL existente
) x
left join tabla_2 on tabla_2.productdescriptionid = x.productdescriptionid
```